# Access 2010 - Multiple one-to-many tables

Tags: forms, ms-access, relationships

The situation I am dealing with seems pretty basic but I can't make it work...

**Scenario:**

One company has many branches and each branch has many addresses as well as many contacts:
[image: Tables relationship]

**I am trying to design several data-entry forms to fill information in three tables:**

Companies, CompanyBranches, Addresses (excluding contacts by now to reduce complexity a bit). I have a cascade of several forms where the Company Details is called by clicking on the CompID, Branch Details is called by clicking on the BranchID etc.:

[image: First - Companies List]

[image: Second - Company Details]

[image: Third - Branch Details]

[image: Fourth - Address]

The problem is to add or modify records. When I click on the Add Branch button in the Company Details form, the Branch Details form appears with blank fields where I can enter the name of the new branch (BranchAddress subform is empty at the moment). But when I close the form after entering the branch name I get an error:

```
You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'Companies'.
```

Same thing when I want to add an additional address for a branch. What do I do wrong?

P.S. When I remove relation between CompanyBranches and Addresses tables then I can add branches with no errors.

P.P.S. I realized that I probably need to add a macro that is used on click event on the Add Branch button:

[image: On Click event Macro]

Comment: Do you have a field on the Branch details form that includes CompID?

Comment: I didn't have CompID in the Branch Details form. I added it after your question but it didn't help. Actually I need to have an option of adding new branches in the Company Details form, not it the Branch Details form. For this purpose I have a command button with a macro on click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out what was wrong with my forms.

First of all, I had to add CompID to the Branch Details form, as was suggested in this thread, and secondly make a bond between the Company Details form and the Branch Details form:

In the Branch Details form, in the properties of the CompID text box under Data tab, in the Default Value row I added a link to the CompID value that is in the Company Details form: =[Forms]![Company Details]![CompID]. Now these two forms are linked by the CompID value, and this value will be written from the Companies table to the corresponding record in the CompanyBranches table at the moment of entering information in the Branch Details form.

Hope my explanation is not even more confusing then my question...
Anyway, thank you to all who participated in solving this issue.

P.S. Same thing with Address Details form. It must have the BranchID in it and a link to the Branch Details form as the default value of the BranchID: =[Forms]![Branch Details]![BranchID].

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you have an issue with the foreign keys. You might want to check that whilst saving a branch, you actually add the id of the Company in the branch. When you remove the relation between both you don't get an error because the Branch doesn't need the id of the Company anymore (both items are now unrelated).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Charles. However i'm not getting what you mean... Or probably me explanation is not good. So Companies and Branches are linked by CompID. Branches and Addresses are linked by BranchID. In the form Company Details I have a subform Branches which lists all branches for the selected company. When I click on the BranchID in the subform I get the Branch Details form for this branch which contains a subform BranchAddresses. The problem is that when I click on the Add Branch button in the form Company Details, enter a branch name and want to close it, I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

On the Branch Detail form property sheet, under Data tab, change `Data Entry` to `No`

Comment: oh after having a second look on our question I noticed that you have a one to many relationship with `Companies` and `CompanyBranches` so to add a new branch the ID of the Company has to be in the Branch Details form. That's what Charles was saying.

Comment: Hi Kefash, thank you for suggestion. I added CompID (the ID field of the company) to the Branch Details form. Still same error. Actually, I am trying to add new branches from the Company Details form. CompID exists in this form. For adding new branches I have a command button with a macro on click event (I attached a screenshot to my post above). Maybe the problem is that Access just can't handle this type of relation? I mean it works well with a single one-to-many relationship but doesn't work with two. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `add branch` button seem to be opening the form to the correct record and based on the screen shots I'm not seeing why you should be getting an error. Try removing referential integrity on the one-to-many relationship between `CompanyBranches` and `Addresses` and see if you get the same error. I wish I had time to re-create your database and trouble shoot with you. Remember to let us know your solution so we too can fully benefit from your question.